# Swift resize image inside imageview

Tags: ios, swift

I have got this code in Swift

```
let image: UIImageView = {
    let v = UIImageView()
    v.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "st")
    v.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    v.frame = CGRect(x:0,y:0,width:100,height:100)
    v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return v
}()
    image.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    image.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor,constant:-170).isActive = true
```

My goal is to have a `UIImageView` with width 100 and height 100, containing an image inside of it with the same measures.  But my image is definitely bigger than 100px.  Even when I change frame to `10px` the image's size doesn't change.

Comment: What `contentMode` are you using for the image view?

Comment: Can you include the code that embeds the image?

Comment: Sorry, just noted the #imageLiteral - can you post a screenshot of the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?

```
    image.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100.0).isActive = true
    image.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100.0).isActive = true
```

Or, am I misunderstanding your question...